# Twisted logarithm power series

Tags: number-theory, power-series

I recently encountered a power series similar to the one of the $\log(1-x)$ of the form

$$
F(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\psi(n)x^n}{n},
$$
where $\psi$ is some Dirichlet character. Has anyone here seen a function like this? Here are some observations I have made:

1) The radius of convergence is the same as for $\log(1-x)$, so the power series converges for $|x| < 1$.

2) If $\psi(n)$ is the trivial characer mod $N$ then $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}-\frac{x^{Nn}}{Nn}=-\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1-x^N}\right)$.

The next interesting case would be when $\psi$ is a quadratic character. I'd be happy about any reference or further observation on these functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a function is actually a combination of logarithms.  Suppose $\psi$ is a Dirichlet character mod $N$, and let $\zeta$ be a primitive $N$th root of unity. The functions $a \mapsto \zeta^{ka}$, for $k=0, ..., N-1$, form a basis of $L^2(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z, \mathbb C)$, hence there exist numbers $b_k \in \mathbb C$ such that

$$\psi(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} b_k \zeta^{kn}$$

for all $n\in \mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$. The numbers $b_k$ are essentially Gauss sums - the Fourier coefficients of $\psi$. Then your function is just

$$-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} b_k \log(1-\zeta^kx).$$

Remark that we don't even need the fact that $\psi$ is a character - it could be any periodic function with a period of $N$, and the "twisted" logarithm would still decompose as above, with different $b_k$'s.

It is an interesting idea, nevertheless. For instance, the value at $x=1$ of your function is $L(\psi, 1)$, a number of significant arithmetic interest.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: @Michalis My pleasure! Don't let your bounty expire ;)

Comment: Sorry, I hope you got it now. I thought it will be automatically rewarded when I accept.